# Pulling conctere revision of file form Kiln via URL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, mercurial, kiln

I am trying to set up source server for debugging projects that are stored on Kiln/Mercurial repository.

I need to get revision of the file by following data:

- Local file path in the repository;
- Number of revision;
- URL repository.

Can I do this via URL? Or there is another workaround for the issue?

P.S. I'd prefer to avoid using Kiln API if possible.

Comment: Kiln has its own StackExchange site.  This should be asked there: http://kiln.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this solution using Kiln API.

There is awesome .Net library that wraps all call to Kiln API called [Kiln.Net](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/kiln-net-library)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't opposed to parsing the HTML, you can find the string with the changeset hash by visiting the following URL:

```
http://<Kiln URL>/File/<path from hg root>/<filename>/rev=<rev #>
```

In the resulting HTML, you can search for:

`<a class="changeset" href="long path" rev="`**rev you want**`">`

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for reply. But the proposed approach is not sufficient because of two reasons: it requires user to be authenticated via forms authentication; it returns html representation of file instead of the original one.